# Database schema design feedback

Tags: database-design, schema

I'd like to develop a simple portfolio manager web application with the following functions:

- Create/Edit/Delete portfolios
- Add/Edit/Remove trades
- Change language of the app (English for now)
- Change name, currency of the portfolio
- Receive security prices updates every second

It's my first experience in modeling a database schema. I'd be glad to receive some feedback.

I attached the schema and the representation of the portfolio page below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Your question is way too broad for here. Schema design is an [iterative process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process). Not even an expert could look at your schema and tell you whether it works or not! You have your schema, code against it, find the flaws, modify the schema and then repeat n (n could be large!) times until it works to your satisfaction. You should start by doing iteration 1 that I've outlined above and come back to us if you have more specific projects!

Comment: Thanks for reply)

Comment: Instead of "more specific projects" that should have been "more specific questions"! ;-)